# Eigen SVD Double Cast

Tags: eigen

I'm trying to use the EIGEN libs. In particular I'm using the SVD.

After the calculation of the singular values I need to perform this operation:

```
svd.singularValues()/svd.singularValues().row(1)
```

which is a vector dived by a scalar.

My questions are:

1) Why this operation gives me:

> main.cpp:149:56: error: no match for ‘operator/’ (operand types are
>   ‘const SingularValuesType {aka const Eigen::Matrix}’ and
>   ‘Eigen::DenseBase >::ConstRowXpr {aka
>   const Eigen::Block, 1, 1, false>}’)

2) How can i copy the values contained into `svd.singularValues().row(1)` in standard "double" variable?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `svd.singularValues().row(1)` is not a scalar but a `1x1` matrix, which is why your code does not compile. Solution:

```
svd.singularValues()/svd.singularValues()(1)
```

and also note that as usual in C/C++, Eigen's matrices and vectors are 0-based indexed, so if you want to normalize by the largest singular values you should do:

```
svd.singularValues()/svd.singularValues()(0)
```